# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable when retrieving matrix diagonal.

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 291*291 matrix and I would like to automatically retrieved only the values (0,1), (1,2), (2,3).... (n-1, n). Is there a straightforward way to do so using loops or a function?

The matrix is the cosine-similarity between texts in a data base:

```
bodies = [d['body'] for d in data]
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(bodies)

matrix =(tfidf * tfidf.T).A
```

Since I want to create a vector, this is how I am attempting to do it:

```
vector = []
for i in range(len(data) -1):
    vector.append(matrix(i, i+1))
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: What is `matrix` in your code? Show the definition

Comment: Use SQUARE BRACKETS, `matrix[i,i+1]`, to index an array

Comment: On the last line try 'vector.append(matrix[i, i+1])' because I guess matrix is the numpy array from your error message. Parenthesis are for functions arguments and brackets [] for elements.

Comment: and to access a memory element in python use need to use "[ ]"(quare brackets) instead of "( )" (circular brackets).

Comment: @Leva done, any suggestions?

Comment: true mate, stupid mistake, thanks!

Comment: Could you PLEASE change the title of your question to something even periferically meaningful re your question body? I don't want to put words in your mouth but _"''numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"_ would be much, much better imvho — Tx Andres...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your matrix is square, you can use [`numpy.diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) with an offset of 1 to acquire your desired values

```
mat.diagonal(offset = 1)
```

The positive offset of 1 acquires the diagonal 1 above the matrix's main diagonal.

---

*Mini demo*:

```
mat = numpy.ones((3,3))
mat[0,1] = 2
mat[1,2] = 3
print(mat.diagonal(offset = 1))
```

Outputs:

```
[ 2.  3.]
```

Comment: This is way cleaner :)

Comment: Great answer @Donkey Kong. Last question, if I want to retrieve the vector as a single column (terms below each other), is there a straightforward way to do so?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by 'retrieve as a column', but yes - you can create a column vector from an array, or print it as a column very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix subscripts use square brackets, not round brackets. You want `matrix[i, i+1]`.